# Convert unconventional string to mysql datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am completely new to php and am wondering how I could go about converting this string :

```
Tue Jan 17 09:17:15 CST 2012
```

into a format that would fit into a MySQL datetime format (24 hour) of

```
01-17-2009 09:17:15
```

I have found the MySQL function FROM_UNIXTIME() that is said to convert from a PHP Timestamp to MySQL DateTime. My problem is getting that original string to the correct PHP Timestamp format.

Comment: Have you tried strtotime? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) - also this is liable to be closed as a duplicate, a very common question.

Comment: @andrewsi I saw it, but since I have an unconventional format (the CST), did not know if it would work. Is there a way to deal with that?

Comment: @hacket - off the top of my head, I don't know. But it'd be worth trying to see.

Comment: That's a time zone as opposed to an unconventional format.  Read the documentation's comments on timezones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick try:

```
$dt = 'Tue Jan 17 09:17:15 CST 2012';
$ts = strtotime( $dt );

echo date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $ts);
```

outputs: `2012-01-17 16:17:15`

The time difference comes from the timezone. My server is on UTC+1 and CST is UTC-6

Comment: I don't think using strtotime is the best way. I prefer DateTime

Answer (score 0):

You can also use mysql function, I am not sure about timezone though.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('Tue Jan 17 09:17:15 CST 2012','%a %b %e %h:%i:%s CST %Y'),'%m-%d-%Y %h:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use \DateTime::createFromFormat if you have php >= 5.3. I prefer this solution over the strtotime one as to manipulate date you use something that means "date" instead of an integer.

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d h:i:s T Y',$dt);
```